# How to Make an Eye Target Bone Move Eye Bones? (Flat Eyes)

Tags: rigging

First let me start by saying something that might help get rid of any confusion.  I made all the bones look like curves.  I will be calling these "bones" rather than calling them curves for this post to also help get rid of any confusion.  Please refer to the photo to help you understand what I'm doing.[image]

So, I need the character's eyes to look at the target bone.  There are some things that I do not want to change so please don't share a method that will require me to change one of the following:

1.) The pupils are flat cylinders that I want to move around on the lens.  I want them to be cylinders, I know there are other ways of creating pupils on a character but this is what I think is best for this character set=up.

2.) I want the eye bones to be close to his eyes so I can move them easily when I don't need the target in certain situations.  Actually, controlling the eyes with individual eye controls and being able to switch between that and an eye target is a common thing in rigs.  Anyways, I want to keep the eye bones.

3.) I want the target bone to move the eye bones, but parenting is not how it should be done because if you want the character to look far left or right and move the target to where it the character would be looking, the pupils will actually go out of his lenses.  So there needs to be some kind of thing, if the target is far away from the eyes and the target moves a lot, it will only move the eyes a little, but if the target is close to the face, it will move the eyes almost as much as the target gets moved.

You see what I'm trying to do?  I just want the character to look at the target when I'm animating with the target, but the target moves the eye bones.  When those eye bones move, that moves the pupils on the eyes.  That way I can choose to animate the eye bones themselves, and/or the target, to move the eyes.

Does anyone know how to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you could try it this way:

- Create a bone that will be tracked, a bone that will be the parent of the pupil object, and a bone that will be the target.

[image]

- Parent the pupil object to its bone.
- Parent the pupil bone to the tracked bone (in *Keep Offset* mode).
- Cut the *Inherit Rotation* relation between the pupil bone and the tracked bone so that it won't make it rotate.

[image]

- Give your tracked bone a *Track To* constraint with the target as *Target*.

[image]

- Give your pupil bone a *Limit Location* constraint, *Pose Space* mode, and constraint it on the right axis so that it will always stick to the eye.

[image]

- Now when you move the target, the pupil follows but sticks to the eye. You may want to add some constraints on the target bone or on the tracked bone if you want to constraint their movements.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This is exactly what I need!!  This not only helps me but anyone else who comes after me looking for answers!  Thank you again so much!

Comment: you're welcome, I think it must be improvable but it's a beginning  ;)

Comment: Okay so I finally tried it and although it works, there are at least two main issues.  One, when the pupil gets to the edges of the eye (left side, right side, top side, and bottom side), the pupil then goes into the eye and disappears.  Second, the pupil is not actually looking at the target.  I mean, yes, the pupil moves in the direction that the target moves, but the pupil is not correctly lined up with the target.  The pupil is ahead of the target, and for example, moves more to the right than where the target would be if it where there, and same with left, top, and bottom side.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your "curves" are custom shapes for your bone rig. You can add a simple "damped track" bone constraint to the pupil's bone, pointing to the target; then you can animate the "influence" parameter to control the pupil either with the target bone (influence 1.0) or the pupil bone (influence 0.0).

[image]

Comment: I already tried this but the problem with it is that the cylinder pupils rotate (because they are facing the target).  I want the pupils to move around the lens without them rotating.  

I know I can get the pupils to move around the lens with a damped track and make sure to move the base of the eye bones back far enough so that the eyes will not just simply rotate, but will also move around the lens.. but even if I do that, how do I stop the pupils from rotating (facing) the target.  Of course I don't want the cylinder pupils to rotate on the lens because the surface will no longer be flat.